Installing APISIX on AWS EKS Fargate
Looking for some guidance on installing APISIX on EKS Fargate
I am installing APISIX via helm chart
helm upgrade --install apisix apisix/apisix \
  -f values.yaml \
  --version "2.8.1" \
  --namespace apisix \
  --create-namespace \
  --set service.type=LoadBalancer \
  --set ingress-controller.enabled=true \
  --set dashboard.enabled=false 

I have created an EFS and mounted in the EKS subnets
Created the storage class, persistence volume and persistence volume claim (pvc)
So far I don't see any settings in the APISIX values.yaml file that allows me to force etcd to use the pvc I created. Found a post that recommended setting the following in the values.yaml file, but that did not work.
persistence:
    existingClaim: "data-apisix-etcd-0"

The other options is to try and install the Bitnami/etcd separately and configure that to use the pvc created.
Wondering if anyone has had any success installing APISIX on EKS Fargate and can share the approach they took.
